# Import Java Project from Eclipse to NetBeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, project

Hy, I have a Java Project, created with Eclipse.
In NetBeans I do "Import From Eclipse" , selecting my workspace. Here comes the first thing: NetBeans doesen't import for example my custom folder res/. So I copy this one in the right directory of the NEbenas workspace. Now this project should be opendend and runned by other people, so I "Export to zip", fine. Then I "Import from zip" on my other computer, but src folder and refferenced libraries are missing...

The main Problem is: 
When Exporting from NetBenas , src folder and referrenced Libraries are missing.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736631/sharing-a-project-between-eclipse-and-netbeans

Comment: Yeah, but i think my problem is giong in another direction