# Grizzly and Jersey standalone jar

Tags: java, maven, jersey, grizzly

I am trying to package Grizzly with Jersey as a single jar using Maven shade plugin. But I always get the message `No container provider supports the type class org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler`

The code works fine in Eclipse, but not in a packaged jar:

```
public class Main {

private static URI getBaseURI() {
    return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(9998).build();
}

public static final URI BASE_URI = getBaseURI();

protected static HttpServer startServer() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Starting grizzly...");
    ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("share.test");
    rc.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
    return GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    HttpServer httpServer = startServer();
    System.in.read();
    httpServer.stop();
}    
}
```

Here is the complete exception

```
$ java -jar target/webServiceTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Starting grizzly...
Mar 20, 2012 12:48:53 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  share.test
Mar 20, 2012 12:48:54 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class share.test.NonJAXBBeanResource
  class share.test.Hello
Mar 20, 2012 12:48:54 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No container provider supports the type class org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:196)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyServerFactory.java:242)
    at share.test.Main.startServer(Main.java:27)
    at share.test.Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

I am building the jar package using maven with

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.5</version>
   <configuration>
   <transformers>
   <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
     <manifestEntries>
      <Main-Class>share.test.Main</Main-Class>
      <Build-Number>1</Build-Number>
     </manifestEntries>
    </transformer>
  </transformers>
 </configuration>
<executions>
 <execution>
  <phase>package</phase>
   <goals>
    <goal>shade</goal>
   </goals>
 </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Do I need to change the shade plugin to include anything else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error looks like the plugin is not merging the META-INF/services records from different jars correctly - if there are multiple files with the same name in META-INF/services directory of several jars, they need to be merged, not replaced one by the other. Check if that is the case.

Comment: Adding the ServicesResourceTransformer that "Merges META-INF/services resources" did solve my problem, thank you Martin. Just needed to add `<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>` to the transformer in the pom.xml Reference: [link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer)

Answer (score 1):

The following links helped me figuring out the solution below:

- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-assemblies.html
- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html
- [How can I merge resource files in a Maven assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607220/how-can-i-merge-resource-files-in-a-maven-assembly)

especially the answer

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11331222/1497139

Instead of using the jar-with-dependencies as the descriptorRef of your assembly-plugin configuration you create our own e.g. in src/assembly/depmerge.xml (see below). This assembly configuration will add a containerDescriptorHandler that cares for the META-INF/services.

run

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

to get a jar file in target which you can call with

```
java -jar target/x.y.-version-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

**pom.xml:**

```
      <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
          <descriptor>src/assembly/depmerge.xml</descriptor>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**src/assembly/depmerge.xml:**

```xml
<!-- 
 see http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-assemblies.html 
 see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html 
-->
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <!-- TODO: a jarjar format would be better -->
    <id>jar-with-dependencies-and-services</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <!-- 
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607220/how-can-i-merge-resource-files-in-a-maven-assembly
     -->
    <containerDescriptorHandlers>
        <containerDescriptorHandler>
            <handlerName>metaInf-services</handlerName>
        </containerDescriptorHandler>
    </containerDescriptorHandlers>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made the stupid mistake. Configure maven-assembly-plugin in pom as well.

Assembly seems to replace META-INF/services and override "com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyContainerProvider
" in File *com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerProvider*

As guide http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/ mentioned, If your project wants to package your artifact in an uber-jar, the assembly plugin provides only basic support. For more control, use the Maven Shade Plugin.

```
  <!-- mvn assembly:assembly -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>XXX.DaemonMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```