# ClassNotFound when using ServicesResourceTransformer in Maven

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I'm trying to use the ServicesResourceTransformer to deal with some problems I'm running into when I build a fatjar ([docoumented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787265/grizzly-and-jersey-standalone-jar)), but I get a ClassNotFound when maven tries to use it:

```
ClassNotFoundException: Class name which was explicitly given in configuration using 'implementation' attribute: 'org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransfor‌​mer' cannot be loaded
```

My full pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>embedly.reverb</groupId>
<artifactId>reverb</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>reverb</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-servlet-webserver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.18-i</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>Main</Main-Class>
                            <Build-Number>1</Build-Number>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please let me know if any more information would be helpful; this Java thang is new to me.

Comment: Please post full pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 2.0 of the plugin. Looks like that class was only introduced recently.

Comment: make sure org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer is not having invalid characters in it due to cut&paste from stackoverflow if your message contains "??" somewhere in that packagename this is probably the case

Comment: This answer seems to be wrong, @artbristol. The class has been available since r691844 ( http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/plugins/trunk/maven-shade-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/shade/resource/?p=691844), dating from 2008-09-03 21:55:12 (revision by jvanzyl). According to the version history of the plugin (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-shade-plugin), this class would be available probably since 1.2, certainly since 1.2.1.

Comment: @Cacovsky Yeah, I guess WolfgangFahl ought to add his solution as an answer if it's the correct one