# Difference between running in IntelliJ and running from a JAR file

Tags: java, jersey, grizzly

I run the following simple example for a Jersey application on a Grizzly server:

```
@Path("example")
public class example {
    @POST
    public Response someMethod(@Context Request r) {
        System.out.println("Received request at : " + LocalDateTime.now());
        Response response = Response.ok().build();
        return response;
    }
}


public class GrizzlyServerMain {

    public static HttpServer startServer(String BASE_URI) throws IOException {

        // Scans for JAX-RS resources and providers in the specified code-package
        final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new PackagesResourceConfig("Application");

        // create and start a new instance of grizzly http server exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
        return GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, resourceConfig);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String BASE_URI = "http://0.0.0.0:8000";

        // Base URI the Grizzly HTTP server will listen on
        startServer(BASE_URI);

        //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

When I run it from IntelliJ, everything works as expected.

> Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:61163', transport:
>   'socket' Dec 30, 2016 4:00:07 PM
>   com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init INFO: Scanning for
>   root resource and provider classes in the packages:   Application Dec
>   30, 2016 4:00:08 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig
>   logClasses INFO: Root resource classes found:   class
>   Application.Greetings   class Application.example Dec 30, 2016 4:00:08
>   PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init INFO: No
>   provider classes found. Dec 30, 2016 4:00:08 PM
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
>   INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.3
>   10/24/2016 03:43 PM' Dec 30, 2016 4:00:08 PM
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start INFO: Started
>   listener bound to [0.0.0.0:8000] Dec 30, 2016 4:00:08 PM
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start INFO: [HttpServer]
>   Started
>   Received request at : 2016-12-30T16:00:13.097
>   Received request at : 2016-12-30T16:00:14.319
>   Received request at : 2016-12-30T16:00:15.583
>   Disconnected from the target VM, address:
>   '127.0.0.1:61163', transport: 'socket'

But when I create a JAR with all the dependencies, and as soon as I send the request from the client, I get:

> WARNING: Exception during FilterChain execution
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.io.OutputBuffer.reset(OutputBuffer.java:217)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Response.reset(Response.java:732)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:168)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:265)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:134)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:78)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:815)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:567)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:547)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Can you please tell me what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Your app appears dependent on a Glassfish server. Your jar doesn't include the server. I'm not sure how, or even if you'd want, to do this.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I wouldn't - thought when choosing "Build Artifacts" in IntelliJ, it puts everything the code needs in the JAR file.

How did you come to check specifically this issue? I don't seem to see a clue to it in the exception message.  PS, I think I see the Grizzly in the JAR file (study_jersey.jar\org\glassfish\grizzly - ZIP archive, unpacked size 9,992,959 bytes)

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException at org.glassfish.grizzly`. You said you're trying to create a stand-alone jar, and I saw calls to Glassfish, a server.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I've opened the JAR archive and there is an org\glassfish\grizzly path inside it with Grizzly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grizzly and Jersey standalone jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787265/grizzly-and-jersey-standalone-jar)

Comment: The classes can exist, but that doesn't mean the server is running/initialized.

Comment: From the stacktrace seems like the exception IllegalStateException is thrown from Response and from JavaDoc [link](https://grizzly.java.net/docs/2.3/apidocs/org/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/Response.html#reset()), this would be thrown when Response is already committed. That's the maximum I could get from what is posted here. Is there any other log apart from this? You may try a very simple GET method to see how it goes.

Comment: `public static <A> A createContainer(Class<A> type, ResourceConfig resourceConfig) throws ContainerException, IllegalArgumentException {
        return createContainer(type, resourceConfig, (IoCComponentProviderFactory)null);
    }` This is the line that fails - I don't really understand why :(

Answer (score 1):

The exception seems to have changed from IllegalStateException to IllegalArgumentException.

Have a look at Java Doc for [ContainerProvider](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.7/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerProvider.html).
 ContainerProvider is an SPI class and its implementation will be provided by the server you are using, in your case the Grizzly server. 
As per Java Doc:

 ***An implementation (a service-provider) identifies itself by placing a provider-configuration file (if not already present), "com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerProvider" in the resource directory META-INF/services, and including the fully qualified service-provider-class of the implementation in the file.***.

So, I think you need to update "META-INF/services" to your jar and add the provider as "GrizzlyContainerProvider" (package qualified).

You can have a look at a similar post:
[Grizzly and Jersey standalone jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787265/grizzly-and-jersey-standalone-jar)